# jqgrid inlineNav add - show save icon on added row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid-inlinenav

I am using the inlineNav option of jqgrid to add a 'add' option to the toolbar. I am also using a actions formatter for edit and delete.
When I add a new row, the newly added row has an edit icon and a cancel icon, whereas the save icon is on the toolbar next to the add.

Is there a way to specify that the newly added row have a save and cancel icon instead of having the edit icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar question.

I ended up rolling my own formatter.

```
    inlineNavAction = function(cellvalue, options, rowObject, isSavedRow){
        if(isSavedRow !== true){
            var rowid = options.rowId;
            var ocl = "id='jSaveButton_"+rowid+"' onclick=jQuery.fn.fmatter.rowactions.call(this,'save'); onmouseover=jQuery(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); onmouseout=jQuery(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); ";
            var str = "<div title='"+$.jgrid.edit.bSubmit+"' style='float:left;' class='ui-pg-div ui-inline-save' "+ocl+"><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-disk'></span></div>";
            ocl = "id='jCancelButton_"+rowid+"' onclick=jQuery.fn.fmatter.rowactions.call(this,'cancel'); onmouseover=jQuery(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); onmouseout=jQuery(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); ";
            str += "<div title='"+$.jgrid.edit.bCancel+"' style='float:left;margin-left:5px;' class='ui-pg-div ui-inline-cancel' "+ocl+"><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-cancel'></span></div>";
            return "<div style='margin-left:8px;'>" + str + "</div>";

        }else{
            return $.fn.fmatter.actions(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
        }   

    }
```

isSavedRow is passed as true in the case of the formatter being called again after a row has been saved due to being added. I also default the rowId to 0. 
Pass false for default operation. 
I took the markup for save and cancel from the source available on github for version 4.5

Usage:

```
formatter:  function(cellvalue,options,rowObject) {
    return inlineNavAction(cellvalue,options,rowObject, (options.rowId!='new_row'));
 }
```

The new_row in

```
(options.rowId!='new_row')
```

is whatever you have set as the default rowId for an added row. new_row is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `formatter` of the `action` column to:

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
               if (cellvalue === undefined && options.rowId === "_empty") {
                  // remove edit and del buttons  
                  options.colModel.formatoptions.editbutton = false;
                  options.colModel.formatoptions.delbutton = false;
               }
           return $.fn.fmatter.actions(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
         },
```

and then in `addParams` of `inlineNav` we have:

```
            addParams: {
                position: "last", 
                rowID: '_empty',
                useDefValues: true,
                addRowParams: {
                url: '....',
                key: true,
                restoreAfterError: false,
                oneditfunc: function(rowId) {
                    // display the save and cancel buttons
                    $("#jSaveButton_" + rowId).show();
                    $("#jCancelButton_" + rowId).show();
                },
        // ... the rest
            },
```